# trouble with switch block variable in c++

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I have an assignment for a class I'm taking where I have to use a switch block to allow the user to select a shape and then determine the area for the shape. below is the (likely unnecessarily long and complicated for what this assignment is) code for this switch statement. C++ is new to me, and so right now my issue is that I cant get the "shape" character to work/apply to the switch block. I run the code and it just goes to the default always, without accepting the input of 1, 2, 3 or 4.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    // variables:
    float area, radius, length, width, base, height, a, b;
    char shape;
    // input
    cout << "Please enter the number corresponding with one of the following "
            "shapes:"
         << endl
         << endl;
    cout << "1. circle" << endl;
    cout << "2. rectangle" << endl;
    cout << "3. triangle" << endl;
    cout << "4. trapezoid" << endl << endl;
    cin >> shape;
    cout << "\n";
    // SWITCH statement:
    switch(shape) {
        {
        case(1):;
            cout << "You have selected: circle" << endl;
            cout << "Please enter the radius of the circle. " << endl;
            cout << "radius: ";
            cin >> radius;
            area = M_PI * pow(radius, 2);
            cout << "The radius entered: [" << radius
                 << "] results in a circle with an area of " << area << ".";
            break;
        }
        {
        case(2):;
            cout << "You have selected: rectangle" << endl;
            cout << "Please enter the length and width of the rectangle. "
                 << endl;
            cout << "length: ";
            cin >> length;
            cout << "width: ";
            cin >> width;
            area = length * width;
            cout << "The length: [" << length << "] and width [" << width
                 << "] entered result in a rectangle with an area of " << area
                 << ".";
            break;
        }
        {
        case(3):;
            cout << "You have selected: triangle" << endl;
            cout << "Please enter the base and height of the triangle: "
                 << endl;
            cout << "base: ";
            cin >> base;
            cout << "height: ";
            cin >> height;
            area = 0.5 * base * height;
            cout << "The base [" << base << "] and height [" << height
                 << "] entered result in a triangle with an area of " << area
                 << ".";
            break;
        }
        {
        case(4):;
            cout << "You have selected: trapezoid" << endl;
            cout << "Please enter the height and lengths of sides a & b: "
                 << endl;
            cout << "height: ";
            cin >> height;
            cout << "side a: ";
            cin >> a;
            cout << "side b: ";
            cin >> b;
            area = ((a + b) / 2) * height;
            cout << "The height [" << height << "], side a [" << a
                 << "], and side b [" << b
                 << "] entered result in a trapezoid with an area of " << area
                 << ".";
            break;
        }
    default: {
        cout
            << "The value entered is not a number that corresponds with one of "
               "the available shapes. Please try again with a number that does."
            << endl;
    }
    }
}
```

obviously I'm doing something wrong, I just hope its something simple/straightforward. Any insight/advice is appreciated!!

Comment: When sharing your code, specially when asking for help, please make sure to properly format your code to help make it as readable as possible. The compiler might not care, but other humans do. As it is currently formatted, a lot of users will see it and skip over the question instead of putting in the effort needed to decode it.

Comment: Do you really want to read a `char`? It looks like you want `int shape;` instead. Because `1 != '1'`.

Comment: Here's a convenient [site](http://format.krzaq.cc/) you can use. Just paste your code into it, and click format :)

Comment: Easiest option to fix: `switch(shape - '0') `

Comment: @TedLyngmo Hmm, what happens if the text extraction sets `std::coin` into fail state? Unless there's code to handle that in the `default` case, this will behave _"unexpectetdly"_. ;-)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Indeed! There are quite a lot of extractions that may set `failbit` already in this program though, so one more would hardly be noticed :)

Comment: yes, im aware my code isnt well formatted, Like I mentioned, I'm new, and will indent it now. thanks for the suggestion!!

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but `case(1):;` is usually written `case 1:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare shape as an 'int' will solve the problem

Comment: Not all but the question is about the switch...ant it will solve that...

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64684599/trouble-with-switch-block-variable-in-c/64684809?noredirect=1#comment114370853_64684599) would do better, wih less impact to the existing logic..

Comment: "Less impact on the logic"??? How? The text printed to the user is "Please enter the number corresponding with one of the following shapes:" and the shape variable declared in a 'char' of course the switch based on a 'int' will not work...changing the value type of shape is right!

Comment: But additionally `std::cin` is left in fail state, and subsequent tries to enter a correct number will  fail, unless everything is cleaned up.

Comment: I don't get it ... the only problem for compiling will be 'M_PI' which is not declared. Adapting that + changing shape type to 'int' will make the switch works as asked by 'Santino'

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! thanks for the help! I didn't mark the value "shape" as an integer, and tried to make a character instead, rookie mistake, I know... also shoutout to the guy who showed me the code formatter, it was helpful and I'll use it in the future.